# Error while adding orml_tokens. 'Orml_tokens` does not have the std feature enabled

Tags: runtime, error, token, orml

Why I have this Error?

```
Tokens: orml_tokens::{Pallet, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>} = 50,
```

[image]

this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

this error originates in the macro `orml_tokens::__substrate_genesis_config_check::is_std_enabled_for_genesis` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

`Tokens` does not have the std feature enabled, this will cause the `orml_tokens::GenesisConfig` type to be undefined

```
use codec::{Decode, Encode, MaxEncodedLen};
use scale_info::TypeInfo;

#[derive(
    Clone, Copy, PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen,
)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub enum CurrencyId {
    
    Native,

    KSM,

    AUSD,
    /// A foreign asset
    ForeignAsset(ForeignAssetId),
}

pub type ForeignAssetId = u32;

impl Default for CurrencyId {
    fn default() -> Self {
        CurrencyId::Native
    }
}

parameter_type_with_key! {
    pub ExistentialDeposits: |currency_id: CurrencyId| -> Balance {
        match currency_id {
            CurrencyId::Native => ExistentialDeposit::get(),
            _ => 0,
        }
    };
}

pub type IBalance = i128;
impl orml_tokens::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Balance = Balance;
    type Amount = IBalance;
    type CurrencyId = CurrencyId;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type ExistentialDeposits = ExistentialDeposits;
    type OnDust = ();
    type MaxLocks = MaxLocks;
    type MaxReserves = MaxReserves;
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
    type DustRemovalWhitelist = frame_support::traits::Nothing;
    type OnNewTokenAccount = ();
    type OnKilledTokenAccount = ();
}
```

Comment: Could you link your repo？Or Cargo.toml，I think there is an error in it.

Comment: Please paste the output here. Don't use a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any pallets that are added to the runtime needs to be no_std enabled

Have a look at how [we](https://github.com/ImbueNetwork/imbue/blob/main/runtime/imbue-kusama/Cargo.toml#L137)(or any other chain) implemented it

Check your Cargo file and make sure you configured it correctly

Comment: yes!!! finally after adding "orml-tokens/std" to cargo toml it works!!!